# ionic2 ion-refresher pull down full page

Tags: ionic2

I have a list and I want to refresh the list when user pulls it down. I expect that only the list should move down when scrolled, and the rest of the components in the page will remain on their positions. But when I pull down the page, the whole page scrolls down, along with any other components on the screen. Any idea how it will work?

Comment: Please add your script here to look

Comment: Please post your template, it will be easier to see what's wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

It will move everything in your ion-content tab.

```
<ion-header>
  <!--Won't scroll -->

</ion-header>



<ion-content>

  <!--Will scroll -->

</ion-content>
```

I guess move anything you don't want to scroll outside of the content.

Comment: If I put something in between ion-header and ion-content then the html file becomes blank.
I want header, then some static text, then a list which is scrollable.
so should I put static text in header?

Comment: Putting a div in between ion-header and ion-content works for me. This is the positioning css i use.

style="position: absolute; width: 100%; background-color: white; top: 40px; height: 35px; left: 0; right: 0;"

But if it won't work for you, you may want to try putting it in the header.

Comment: I've updated my answer if you wouldn't mind marking it correct, thanks!